# Lotus Notes 8.5 - Sort the name of the recipients in the "To" field

Tags: lotus-notes

How to sort the name of the recipients in the "To" field when I sending an email in Lotus Notes 8.5? For e.g., if I sending an email to:  Bob Michigan, Texas Ranger and Alabama Noob, I want the names sorted alphabetically when the email is received by each of them.

Answer (score 1):

There is no function by default that can do this. If you have access to Domino Designer (Software to change functions in Lotus Notes), then it would be easy to write a so called `Input translation formula` in the `EnterSendTo` field that would then look like this:

```
@Sort( @ThisValue )
```

With formula- language you could even sort by last- name using a little more complex formula.

Without Domino Designer there is no way to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you. Will try and test that in LN in a few hours and report. I am new to Lotus Note and am not sure if I have access to Domino Designer. Nevertheless, I will respond in a few hours.